# how to avoid cpanm stopping installation waiting for a prompt that is shown only in Build.log

Tags: perl, cpanm

Instaling PGPLOT the install gets stopped for ever here:

```
$ cpanm PGPLOT
--> Working on PGPLOT
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/K/KG/KGB/PGPLOT-2.21.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring PGPLOT-2.21 ... OK
Building and testing PGPLOT-2.21 ...
```

Looking at the Build.log seems that it is waiting for a prompt answer

```
$ tail ~/.cpanm/build.log 
       -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lcpgplot -lpgplot -lX11 -lpng -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6 -L/usr/lib -lgfortran -lm     \

chmod 755 blib/arch/auto/PGPLOT/PGPLOT.so
cp PGPLOT.bs blib/arch/auto/PGPLOT/PGPLOT.bs
chmod 644 blib/arch/auto/PGPLOT/PGPLOT.bs
Manifying blib/man3/PGPLOT.3
make: warning: Clock skew detected. Your build may be incomplete.
make: Warning: File `Makefile' has modification time 3e+02 s in the future
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /home/pmg/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin/perl "-Iblib/lib" "-Iblib/arch" test.pl
Default Device for plot tests [recommend /XSERVE] ?
```

How can I avoid this question either forcing defaults or given the option through env. vars?

[UPDATE] FIX

From the Russell answer I exported the variable for device

```
 export PGPLOT_DEV=/XSERVE; cpanm PGPLOT
```

And connected with x11vnc to the server (to the main display) for closing all windows the pgplot test was displaying.

[NOTE] don't try to install pgplot perl lib under screen even with ssh -X, chances are that you are not in the same computer you starter your original screen and the X redirection will not work. You can circumvent that limitation with a vnc connection to main display or you will not being able to finish the installation. xrdp and other vnc that open a new session will not work. You need to share the main display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading test.pl in the distribution, it checks the PGPLOT_DEV environment variable.  It looks like the valid values are /XSERVE for Unix/Linux and /PNG for Windows.

Comment: You could report this as a bug here: [link](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=PGPLOT)

Comment: Not sure if it is a bug or cpanm feature. cpanm hide you a lot of input, sending almost everything to STDERR. Seems that interactive questions are also sent to STDERR. The issue here seems to be that the question had a default, and seems that cpanm is designed to take all defaults and not bother you with questions BUT something did not work well here between cpanm and PGPLOT install. But I don't know who is the culprit.

Comment: Anyway reported as 'issue' at pgplot bugtraking.

Comment: @PabloMarin-Garcia it's a bug that PGPLOT prompts when PERL_MM_USE_DEFAULT is set to 1. It should use a sensible default, or if that's not possible, die (so that you can try again interactively — `cpanm --prompt` is handy here).